# Angular not able to import library

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, angular-cli, js-beautify

I'm installing js-beautify from https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-beautify

via `npm install js-beautify --save`

Then adding import to my app.component.ts

documentations says to

```
import jsbeautifier
```

But it needs quotes, so I'm using

```
import 'jsbeautifier'
```

but after that when I'm trying to use it I'm receiving error:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/app/app.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jsbeautifier' in '/home/oscar/IdeaProjects/lodashteatcherv4/src/frontend/src/app'
 @ ./src/app/app.component.ts 14:0-22
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/main.ts
```

I tried also this import

```
import '../../node_modules/js-beautify/js/lib/beautify.js'
```

I'm using angular cli 2/4

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing 3rd Party Applications with Angular-CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42031389/installing-3rd-party-applications-with-angular-cli)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing Python instruction from documentation `import jsbeautifier`. In order to import this beautifier in javascript (client or nodejs) you need to do it this way:

```
import { js_beautify } from 'js-beautify'
```

However, I doubt you really want to do it this way, code beautification should probably not be part of your `app.component.ts`.

Comment: you may need its typing : `npm i @types/js-beautify`

Comment: Guys, its working but I wonder why I was able to do:
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'hammerjs';
import 'prismjs';
in my app.component.ts ?

Comment: You can do it because those modules exist. There is no `jsbeautifier` module you can import so it was not working.