# Separation of the innerHTML elements in a code format using Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

The result of my innerHTML is like below in javascript.

```
"<ol><li>Testing1</li><li>Testing2</li></ol>"
```

Can I align it in a code format as below using regex or anyother? any suggestion on this ?

```html
<ol>
  <li>Testing1</li>
  <li>Testing2</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: you mean doing it in the developer console or... do you want to display it on the webpage or what's your purpose?

Comment: See [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: As long as your code is properly formatted in the actual file you're working with, you should not concern about formatting the code rendered on the client-side. It's just waste of time ...

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that question - that question is about how to *wrap elements, attributes and values with spans with their own classes.*. This is something pretty different.

Answer (score 3):

The problem [isn't trivial](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8348545). One issue with regular expressions is that Javascript's can't handle nested matching delimiters in most cases. Another issue is that you need to keep track of self-closing tags (`<div />`, or tags which don't have closing tags (`<img>`, `<input>`) *and* programmatically identify whether the text you're currently processing is part of structured HTML markup, or whether it's just plain text (like `<textarea>foo<div>bar</div></textarea>`).

It would probably be easier to use a library designed for this purpose, so as not to re-invent the wheel. [js-beautify](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify) is one option:

```js
const input = "<ol><li>Testing1</li><li>Testing2</li></ol>";
console.log(html_beautify(input, { 'indent-size': 2 }));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-beautify/1.10.2/beautify-html.js"></script>
```

Comment: Upvote! I'm wrong when thinking this question is about: Converting string to node in javascript. lol

Comment: How to use in angular platforms

Comment: Yup.. I 've found it for adding it in the angular platform(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46753490/angular-not-able-to-import-library). :)

Comment: The main problem is that HTML isn't a regular language, so not really suitable for parsing by regular expressions alone, though they can be useful for identifying tokens. :-) BTW, `<div />` is just a start tag, div elements aren't void elements so must have start and end tag. `<img />` is a better example, though the `/` is redundant and `<img>` is sufficient ([*HTML start tags*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#start-tags)).